# a von Neumann algebra factor of type $II_1$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a type $II_1$ factor,is it true that  two projections in $M$ are equivalent iff they have the same trace?

what is the precise definition of $II_1$ factor?Is it an infinite dimensional factor with a unique normal tracial state?

Comment: A $II$-factor is a factor that does contain finite projections but no minimal projections. A $II_1$ factor is a $II$ factor where $1$ is a finite projection. 
One can show that every factor von-Neumann Algebra is of type $II_1$ if and only if it is infinite-dimensional and there exists a *faithful* normal tracial state. 

Now, if I have two equivalent projections it is clear that they have the same trace. The other direction I don't know. But I suppose it already fails in a finite-dimensinoal setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common definition is that a II$_1$-factor is a finite factor (that is, the identity is finite as a projection) with no minimal projections. This implies the existence of a unique faithful trace.

An infinite-dimensional factor with a unique faithful (this is important) trace is II$_1$ (the normality follows). This is easy to see, since the existence of the trace precludes types I$_\infty$, II$_\infty$ and III, and infinite-dimensionality precludes types I$_n$.

And, as you say, on a II$_1$ factor if two projections have the same trace, then they are equivalent. This follows directly from the fact that due to comparison (and faithfulness of the trace), non-equivalent projections have different trace.

Comment: You mentioned that the proposition can be proved directly due to comparison.But given any two projections $p,q$  in a II11factor $M$,they may not be compared.

Comment: No. Any two projections in any factor can be compared.

Comment: Would you mind showing the proof in details?

Comment: It's in every book on von Neumann algebras. Given $p,q\in M$, there is a central projection $r\in Z(M)$ such that $rp\preceq rq$ and $(1-r)q\preceq(1-r)p$.